# SASS :after :hover selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

How do I use a SASS selector within a pseudo selector on a hover state? Wanting to write less code and clean this up.

Preferred method, not working:

```
div {
    a {
        transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        &:after {
            content: ">>";
            left: 10px;
            :hover & {
                left: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As opposed to:

```
div {
    a {
        transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        &:after {
            content: ">>";
            left: 10px;
        }
        &:hover {
            &:after {
                left: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `:hover &` targets `:hover` *inside* of the `:after`, rather than on it, does it not?

Comment: On the first example it does. Trying to grab the outside parent element as a selector.

Comment: Did you even *look* at the compiled output?  When there's only one possible order of selectors that will work, you have to write the selectors in that order.  No amount of wishing will change anything.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `&:hover:after {}` for targeting the `after` pseudo-element of the element being hovered over.

`&:after:hover {}` would select the `after` pseudo-element and used on hover it.

Comment: That's probably as clean as I can get it, I suppose. Not bad.

Comment: An explanation would be nice.